# Help Text ONLY on a specific picklist value

Tags: picklist, helptext

is it possible to display a help text exclusively on the default PickList value as set on a custom object?

Thank you for your help,

I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not possible on a standard page layout. You'd have to go the visualforce way to do something like this.

Comment: Thank you so much, this gives a good indication on how to proceed.